What is the limit for needs for citations when it comes to well known facts?
I am aware that this question is quite broad, but I am curious about what the limits are here. Probably the answer is a "It depends", but I am still eager to hear what other people thing about this.
I have recently started to write my final thesis. In the section I am currently writing I discuss a number of file formats provided by Autodesk, a company in the CAD sector. I am including a related factoid about Adobe, another company, because their business behaviour is very similar to the behaviour of Autodesk.
This is the segment of text that I am concerned about:

In our case we would need to use the NWD format, that does not only save references to other model files, but also stores geometry data \cite{NWF_BaseInformation}. Here again we find a repeating pattern: The usage of the format itself it bound to a license, but viewing and reviewing the files is available easily. This was already seen in \ref{sec:dwfdwfx}. This repeating pattern is an indicator that structures like this are part of the business model of Autodesk. Similar structures are found across the industry with Adobe being well known for having very similar approaches concerning Adobe Acrobat Pro and the Adobe Acrobat Reader when it comes to PDF files.

The question is: What can I assume the reader of my thesis already knows? The difference between Adobe Pro and Adobe Reader is known to everyone in my professional network, including my professor. Is that enough for me to not have put a citation for this (and other similar) factoids?

Sorry for the frame challenge, but is the business model of either company really relevant for a scientific work?

I am considering different 3D model formats provided by Autodesk. As the thesis is sponsored by a company (and a project that has to be implemented), they also have an interest in the results of my work. Sketchy business models like this are a strong deterrant to using a format, so when it comes to the decision, which format will ultimately be used, I do think it is relevant.

@monamona Are you calling issuing a license "sketchy"?

I would suggest the line for "well-known facts" is closer to "PDF is a file format" than what you're talking about.

No, sketchy might be the wrong word. Perhaps forcibly closed is a better one here. My mistake.

It is almost always better to cite than not to cite. In particular it provides context to a reader. And, you probably don't know all of your readers.
For context, it isn't possible to copyright "common knowledge" and thus, not necessary to cite it. But the tricky part is that "common knowledge" is a judgement call and what might be common in one community may not be in a wider one. And some omissions might be construed by some as plagiarism, though unlikely in this case.
Providing complete context, however, is a very important academic value.
